# UserControl declaration missing from Web Application designer file

Tags: .net, user-controls, wap

I have just converted my web site to a web application project which generated a designer file for each .aspx file.
Unfortunately the designer file does not have declarations for my usercontrols on the page and the build fails. If I manually add the declaration to either the designer file or the code behind for the usercontrols it works.
I have declared the usercontrol in both the web.config and at the page level.

ERROR:

```
'acEditStaffName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the errors you get after the build failure? Thanks.

Comment: 'acEditStaffName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: The "acEditStaffName" is the ID of my usercontrol that is not declared and can't find on the page obviously.

Comment: The build fails when code behind is trying to access the usercontrol by ID. So if I go and manually declare that control in either the designer file or the code behind with something like this: 
Protected WithEvents acEditAdditionalContactComapny As modules_autoCompleteControl 
it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think i found a fix for this issue.

1. Remove designer file
2. Remove the <%@ Register elements in the html file
3. Convert to webapplicaion --> designer file will be recreated
4. Add again the register elements..
5. Edit in designer file the namespace of your usercontrol to the right namespace

This worked for me after struggling for more than an hour..